# Back up android with adb backup

Tags: android, adb, backup, pull, smartphone

With the backup command you could make a complete backup of android smartphones, now that I know only the pull command remains but it is not like the backup command, are there alternatives?

Answer (score 6):

The adb backup command may be able to make a complete backup of an Android smartphone, but nowadays it becomes more and more useless:

1. adb backup can only backup apps that allow backup at all (an app has to declare `allowBackup=true` in it's `AndroidManifest.xml` or don't have such an entry at all). If it sets `allowBackup=false` then adb backup can not get any data on this app.
2. Cryptographic keys stored in AndroidKeystore can not be extracted, they are bound to the phone hardware. https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore
3. adb backup fails on recent apps that have targetSDK level to 31 or higher - only exception: the app is a debuggable app (`debuggable="true"` in AndroidManifest.xml) but this is never the case for apps from Play Store or third party download sites). adb backup was marked deprecated years ago, seems like Google wants to finally cut it off. https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#adb-backup-restrictions

Comment: Ok, but what is the current alternative to that command? And which allows the entire android backup?
The various tools that do android backups rely on adb, for example andriller, which adb command are they based on?

Comment: @tecno78 On unrooted devices there is no real alternative. If you can not access the data you can not backup or transfer them. If a tool uses adb backup command it will fail. Some apps allow Google cloud backup and others can be transfered to a new device using direct USB connection. That are the ways Google allows.

Comment: Tools like andriller are adb based and work, without root, something escapes me

Comment: @tecno78 I did not say adb backup does not work at all,  there are still apps which allow backup and on older phones adb backup also still works for apps that allow it, but the number of apps is getting smaller and smaller and on newer devices for newer apps it doesn't work at all.

Comment: ok, but then tools like andriller or similar that back up all android use adb only for the connection with the device, then for the backup they do not use the adb "backup" command but it is the program with which the tool was developed back up?

Comment: @tecno78 Have you tried to create an abckup of an app that refuses backup via adb? Most likely you will get the same result using andriller.

Comment: So andriller and the like use the adb "backup" function to extract the data?
However apart from applications, data such as images, audio, media in general are extracted right?
The alternatives are then the adb command "pull" or root the device and then perform the copy with commands like dd?

Comment: @tecno78 I don't use andriller and such tools, you say it uses adb backup. As I don't use it I don't know how it works and what data it backup.

Comment: No I'm not sure, I was just asking

Comment: @tecno78 as I wrote for app private data of non-debug apps on a non-rooted device there is only adb backup, thus if these tools claim to create a backup they can only use adb backup and are affected by the problems I mentioned. All the other data on the sdcard section can be accessed by commands like adb pull.

Comment: ok, clearer this way, in order to root the device can you tell me any particular tool?

Comment: @tecno78 - you want topjohnwu/Magisk on github for root.  I'm not posting a link just because there are so many fake (maklware) links out there that it's good to get in the habit of going straight to github.  Termux app can be helpful with root; tar and split are available.  Your USB storage is under /mnt/media_rw/  .

Comment: Note that you cannot root the device to create a backup of it because rooting the device will require doing factory reset. Google really dropped the ball when it comes to backups!