Unable back up, and restore android app data with adb
I just got my new phone (Xiaomi duoqin F22 pro), and want to migrate my savegames, and other app data from my old phone (qin F21pro) to it using adb. The older phone has no google services, not unlocked, and not rooted.
I tried using adb to create back ups, and used
adb shell pm list packages | sort
to get a list of packages (the command prompt said failure), but if I wrote
adb backup -f appdata.ab -all -apk -nosystem
It created a backup which had the size of 1,6gigs (which is far less than the stored userdata not speaking of the apks). However if I try to restore that save, I can see the package names, and it takes like 10 minutes to finish, but nothing changes in the phone.
If I try to back up a single apk using the package names I can see in /android/data, it prompts the backup intention, but it creates 1kb backup files.
Both phones are used with the same PC, same cable.

adb backup doesn't work anymore for apps that have a targetSDK level of 31 or higher (developed for Android 12+). See https://stackoverflow.com/q/74387730/150978

But the apps I have are for like min. android 8, and the phone itself is android 11.

Then most likely the apps you try to backup have allowBackup=false in their AndroidManifest.xml.

But I cant access to that without root. Afaik the different adb version can also cause this problem. What might be the good version for a late 2020 phone?

If you suspect adb to be a problem just don't use it. adb backup is just a shorthand for adb shell and then bu with piping the output into a file on PC side. If you save the file on Android itself adb shell is only used for displaying the messages and do no harm to the backup file.

And how could I do that? I am really new to this.

You have already use adb shell without argument you get a shell that is running in the phone. Then you can type bu --help to see the backup arguments. These arguments are next to identical to the one of adb backup as adb does nothing more to send them to bu on the phone.

Thanks. But on the phone I always get /system/bin/sh: adb: inaccessible or not found

On PC side you execute adb shell and then  you are already on the phone, no need to execute adb again. Just execute bu then.
